# Enterprise Library 5.0 don't show namespace Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data

Tags: class, ado.net, namespaces, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I was using Visual Studio 2008 with Enterprise Library 4.0. It is working fine and showing namespace                                  Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data. Now I installed VS 2010 and Enterprise Library 5.0.(because 4.0 sowsn't support vs 2010 ).

But the problem is Enterprise Library 5.0 doesn't show Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data. Is there another namespace in 5.0 thriugh which I can access the Database class which comes under Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data namespace?

please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably targeting .NET Framework Client Profile.  The Data Access Block has dependencies on System.Data.Oracle and requires the full .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else hitting this problem with moving their DAAB-based app to .NET4, entlib5 is supplied with the source code installable via e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0\src\Enterprise Library 5.0 - Source Code.msi`

Running that msi and accepting the defaults creates a `EntLib50Src` folder under your Documents area. If you go into `EntLib50Src\Blocks\Data` and open `Data.2010.sln` you can change the target framework to `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`.

This will create a bunch of errors related to the `System.Data.Oracle` dependency. Remove the reference to it, and then exclude the `Oracle` parts of the project and comment out any `Oracle` references in the common code.

If you then recompile with strong name signing on you can use the output assemblies (`Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll` and `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll`) with `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`. You do have to distribute `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll` from the e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0\Bin` area but this is client profile-compatible.

Note that the above works if you're not needing Oracle support in your app. Mine doesn't, its SQL Server and VistaDB only. The above should work with any non-Oracle db compatible with ADO.NET.